# Upload multpile files with several inputs

Tags: php, html, ajax

My HTML code is (AJAX method) :

```
    <?php
    $i = 1;
    while($i < 10){
        ?>
        <div id="photoManagement<?php echo $i; ?>">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="contenu" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Choix de la photo <?php echo $i; ?></label>
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <input id="photo<?php echo $i; ?>" type="file" name="image<?php echo $i; ?>" accept="image/*">
            </div>
        </div><br /><br />

        <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
            <div id="image_preview<?php echo $i; ?>" class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="thumbnail hidden">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/5" alt="">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h4></h4>
                        <p></p>
                        <p><button id="cancelImg<?php echo $i; ?>" type="button" class="btn btn-flat btn-danger">Annuler</button>
                        <button id="sendImg<?php echo $i; ?>" location.hred = "#portfolioImg1" class="pull-right btn btn-dark btn-theme-colored btn-flat mr-5">Ajouter</button></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        $i++;
        }
    ?>
```

The  tag is far behind. That's why it is not appear.

My PHP (AJAX method) :

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

if( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) && ( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest' ) ) //sécurité pour ne pas avoir d'accès direct sur le fichier
{
    include('../MODEL/sqlConnexion.php');
    //Partie traitement des photos
    foreach($_FILES as $photo)
    {
        $key = key($_FILES);
        if (isset($photo))
        {
            if ($photo['error'] == 0)
            {
                // Test pour voir si l'extension du fichier est bien autorisée
                $file_path = pathinfo($photo['name']);
                $file_extension = $file_path['extension'];
                $allowed_extensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');
                if (in_array($file_extension, $allowed_extensions))
                {
                    // Test pour voir si le fichier n'est pas trop gros
                    if ($photo['size'] <= 1048576)
                    {
                        $response['check'] = 'OK';
                        $path = '../images/chevaux/' . $_POST['horseName'] . '/' . $key . '.' . $file_extension;
                        $folder = '../images/chevaux/' . $_POST['horseName'];
                        if (!is_dir($folder))
                            {
                                mkdir($folder);
                            }
                        move_uploaded_file($photo['tmp_name'], $path);
                    }
                    else
                    {           
                        $response[$nomImage] = "Le fichier " . $key . " est trop volumineux.";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $response[$nomImage] = "L'extension du fichier " . $key . " n'est pas prise en charge, les extensions prises en charge sont jpg, jpeg, gif, et png.";
                }

            }
            elseif ($photo['error'] != 4)
            {
                $response[$nomImage] = "Le fichier " . $key . "est en erreur.";
            }
        }
    }
    if ((count($response) == 1) && ($response['check'] == 'OK'))
    {
        $response['check'] = 'OK';
    }
    else
    {
        $response['check'] = 'NOTOK';
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

The folder is created on the server, but only the first file of the first input is uploaded in. That is why I didn't put all the javascript code which is working perfectly. The only problem on the code is on "move_uploaded_file".

Do you have any idea?

Comment: do you have read/write access on the folder

Comment: Yes, the first file is correctly uploaded atm. The problem is the next files..

Comment: does it say the folder exists the second time round?

Comment: It seems to be OK. I tried to count number of time that the folder was created and it returns 1 always or 0 if it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution. In fact, the variable $key was always the same. So the picture was always erased with the loop.

I had to write :

```
foreach($_FILES as $key=>$photo)
```

To have the $key value. And I keep $photo with the same use. All is OK now.

Hope it can help.